# Error at typescript type declaration of graphql query

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, apollo

I'm using Nuxt.js (Vuex) + Apollo.

Now, I'm working hard to get Typescript into this project, especially around Graphql. I read this [article](https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/typescript-graphql-files-modules) and generate type file but it does not work. I cannot import query at `.ts` file in store directory.

generated type file. (`~/graphql/types.d.ts`)

```js
declare module '*/activate.gql' {
  import { DocumentNode } from 'graphql'; <- another problem: ts says "error TS2307: Cannot find module 'graphql'"
  const defaultDocument: DocumentNode;
  

  export default defaultDocument;
}
```

this is generated by `codegen.yml`:

```
schema: http://localhost:3000/graphql
generates:
  ./graphql/types.d.ts:
    documents: ./graphql/**/*.gql
    plugins:
      - typescript
      - typescript-graphql-files-modules
```

I cannot import `activate` query at store. (`~/store/user.ts`)

```
import activate from '~/graphql/mutations/activate.gql'; <- "error TS2307: Cannot find module '~/graphql/mutations/auth/activate.gql'"
```

According to the above document, this will work...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6t8N.png)

Directory structure is here.

```
- graphql
  |- queries
  |- mutations
     |- activate.gql
  |- types.d.ts

- store
  |- user.ts

- codegen.yml
```

Part of `package.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxt/types": "^2.15.4",
    "@nuxtjs/apollo": "^4.0.1-rc.3",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.12.2",
    "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "^1.4.1",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.2.2",
    "@nuxtjs/sitemap": "^2.4.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.10.0",
    "cookie-universal-nuxt": "^2.1.4",
    "graphql": "^15.5.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.11.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "nuxt": "^2.14.0",
    "nuxt-basic-auth-module": "^1.3.3",
    "nuxt-jsonld": "^1.5.0",
    "nuxt-typed-vuex": "^0.1.22",
    "redirect-ssl": "^2.0.0",
    "vee-validate": "^3.4.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-infinite-loading": "^2.4.5",
    "vue-lazyload": "^1.3.3",
    "vue-slick": "^1.1.15",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "^1.21.3",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "^1.21.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-graphql-files-modules": "^1.18.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "^1.17.15",
    "@nuxtjs/google-fonts": "^1.2.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.3",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.9.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "husky": "^4.3.0",
    "jest": "^26.1.0",
    "lint-staged": "^10.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "sass-loader": "^9.0.3",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.4"
  },
}
```

I would greatly appreciate it if you could answer...

Comment: Do you have the `graphql` package installed? Maybe include your `package.json` in your question. You will need to fix the error in your declaration. This will probably solve the second error you get.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I have already installed `graphql` in this project and can find `graphql` packege in `node_modules`...

Answer (score 2):

I got it!!
I'm not sure about this solution is best, but, by generating declaration of queries to `global.d.ts`, I can import queries from anywhere without errors!!

If you know better solution, please imform me.

`codegen.yml`:

```
schema: http://localhost:3000/graphql
generates:
  ./graphql/types.d.ts:
    documents: ./graphql/**/*.gql
    plugins:
      - typescript
  ./global.d.ts:
    documents: ./graphql/**/*.gql
    plugins: 
      - typescript-graphql-files-modules
```